# What is the best way to to generate kml file by xls

Tags: android, kml, xls, google-earth

I am currently doing the android apps to determine the road surface condition. When i have all handphone sensor data in text file format, i need to convert to kml. to get the allignment, i convert the file to xls. Then i have 3 way to convert it.

1. By android apps to convert the kml.
2. By manually, 
     -retrieve coordinate from the file and save it to xls.
     -use excel equation to decide the line color by using accelerometer and orientation data
     -put to www.earthpoint.us/ExcelToKml.aspx to convert xls to kml
     -put the kml to google earth to do analyzing
3. By automated. could be VB, JAVA and etc. but i m not familiar which program can do it
     nicely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not completely sure what you are wanting to do here, but if you build this all in android then you can simply use Java Regular Expressions (java.util.regex) to parse out the sensor data into kml. You would need to open the sensor file, parse, and then output into the kml file.
2. I think you have all the steps to do this manually.
3. If you are building the app as described in #1, then you don't need this. All those program languages you described, can do what you want.